# Should I expect any problems for regularly querying PeakWorkingSet64 and other similar counters in Process object?

Tags: c#, .net, process

Here's my scenario. I have a 64 bit COM client process that runs C# code. The COM client process instantiates an unmanaged C++ COM server using DCOM, obtains the process id of that COM server (the server has an interface that has a method which returns that process id) and then calls

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById( processId );
```

to obtain a `Process` reference and stores this reference for the lifetime of the COM server.

The client then instantiates an object in the COM server and calls one of its methods to process data and so feeds chunks of data to the server one by one. Sometimes it so happens that after the method has been called for some thousands of times (which typically takes dozens of hours) the COM server process runs out of memory and the next request to it yields `E_OUTOFMEMORY` `HRESULT` and once that happens the client lists all the processes in the system and dumps the fields of all `Process` objects such as `PeakWorkingSet64` and others and then restarts the server process.

I reviewed several dozens of such dumps and clearly the server process looks quite overweight at the point it returns `E_OUTOFMEMORY` - something like 1,5 gigabytes of memory are consumed while it typically consumes something like 100 megabytes when it serves usual requests.

So I suspect there's some resource leak which I have to trace. To do so I need to detect the moments at which counters like `PeakWorkingSet64` change significantly. So I want to add the code that dump this counters after processing each chunk which is something like once in ten seconds.

My question is - will this likely cause any problems such as for example some deadlocks or resource shortage or anything else caused by this counter possibly not designed for frequent reading?

Comment: You want to read the counter once every 10 seconds? taskmgr already does it every second (probably with `NtQueryInformationProcess`), so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ken2k: I'd guess taskmgr is an unmanaged program so it uses Win32 directly.

Comment: Use `Process.Refresh()` instead of always getting a new handle. If you're not disposing the process handless, you might be getting into trouble. When you no longer need the instance, call `Process.Dispose()`. The problem is that the GC has no idea about the unmanaged resources being used, so you might be running out before the GC runs even once to dispose of the old handles :) If you do it safely, you can query often with no trouble.

Comment: @sharptooth The `Process` class internally uses `NtQueryInformationProcess` to retrieve all stats about a given process. The .Net framework just wraps the Win32 API with P/Invoke.